# How to solve the import error in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, python, execjs

I have the following js code:

```
function getSlideAnswer(responseId, fpToken, coordinateX, traceData) {

    coordinateX = Math.floor(coordinateX);
    var encryptData = {
        "track": traceData,
        "x": coordinateX + "",
        "p": "0,0",
        "finger": fpToken
    };
    var t = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(responseId.substr(0, 16));
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(encryptData), t, {
        iv: t,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }).ciphertext.toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
execjs._exceptions.ProgramError: TypeError: 'JSON' is undefined
```

How to solve the error?

Comment: I used python and imported `execjs` module.

Comment: Coincidence :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57735174/how-to-solve-the-js-problem-of-typeerror-json-is-undefined

Comment: Probably worth noting the project is EOL and not being maintained: https://pypi.org/project/PyExecJS/ Apparently, it doesn't provide the `JSON` object added in ES5. The project points to [PyV8](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyv8/) as a possible alternative.

Comment: An old browser ? JSON object is quite new feature, some a bit older do not know it...

Comment: @Tom - 10 years old at this point, it was part of ES5 (December 2009). :-) Even IE8 had `JSON`. But the OP said above they aren't using a browser, they're using the `execjs` module in Python.

Comment: Sorry did not noticed tags on mobile, code looks like JS and had similar compatibility problems with IE in XP - would tell 8(?).

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. What should I do to solve it?

Comment: @John Can you show us the Python code you use to run this?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace strigify by string concatenation in JS or Python.
Not sure about parameter types, but an example in JS:

```js
function getSlideAnswer(responseId, fpToken, coordinateX, traceData) {

    coordinateX = Math.floor(coordinateX);
    var encryptData = '{"track":"' + traceData +
        '","x":"' + coordinateX +
        '","p":"0,0","finger":"' + fpToken +
    '"}';
    var t = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(responseId.substr(0, 16));
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encryptData, t, {
        iv: t,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }).ciphertext.toString().toUpperCase();
}
Test()

function Test() {
    var traceData="foo", coordinateX = 123, fpToken = "bar";
    var encryptData = {
        "track": traceData,
        "x": coordinateX + "",
        "p": "0,0",
        "finger": fpToken
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(encryptData));
    var encryptDataStrigified = '{"track":"' + traceData +
        '","x":"' + coordinateX +
        '","p":"0,0","finger":"' + fpToken +
    '"}';
    console.log(encryptDataStrigified);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(encryptData) == encryptDataStrigified);
}
```